# Parse ObjectId Null

Tags: objective-c, object, null, parse-platform

To make this short and sweet: I have a tableview with a custom cell, and I want to show the objectId in it. This is the code I have... why will it not show anything or log anything?

```
UILabel *objectIdLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    objectIdLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"objectId"];
```

Thanks

Comment: if the `object` is a PFObject... you can reference the objectId like so... `[object objectId]`;

Comment: Also, how are you getting the `object`? Are you sure your calling `[tableView reloadData]` after making a PFQuery to the parse database? `tableView` is the `UITableView` of the `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` your using to embed your tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[object objectId];
```

objectId is a property of PFObject class so treat it as that.
Check this out: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate it! Any explanation why the other way does not produce the same result?

Comment: @Nicholas this kind of thing just needs to refer to Parse docs.